# Core Data Relation between Objects

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

i have a question about how create a relation between 2 NSObjects in Core Data.

First i have this CoreData Structure.

[image: Core Data]

There is a Relationship between files and forms. A form could have multiple files, but one file could only have one form.

I have created the NSObjects only with Swift (so no Bridging Header) - and have now 2 Core Data NSObject Classes:

```
class Forms: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var uuid: String
@NSManaged var damagenumber: String
@NSManaged var internalnumber: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var street: String
@NSManaged var postalcode: String
@NSManaged var city: String
@NSManaged var country: String
@NSManaged var templateJSON: String
@NSManaged var formname: String
@NSManaged var files: NSSet

}

class Files: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var url: String
@NSManaged var forms: Forms

}
```

My files are here as a NSSet.

So, i would like for example add a form with 5 files. So startet with something like this:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Forms")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

let newFormObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Forms", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Forms

newFormObject.setValue(uuid, forKey: "uuid")
......
```

// insert files

```
 for index in 0...4 {

     var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Files")
     request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

     let newFileObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Files", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Files
     newFileObject.setValue(arrFiles[index], forKey: "url")

}
```

Ok everything works fine. BUT: How do i connect this 2 Objects? If u use Obj-C NSObjects instead of Swift i have a few Methods to add a File to a Form. But how can i do this in Swift only?

And if i have a relation - how do i read all File Objects from a certain Form?

**Edit:**

i changed now the line:

```
@NSManaged var files: NSSet
```

to

```
@NSManaged var files: [Files]
```

And using in the loop:

```
newFormObject.files.append(newFileObject)
```

And this brings me the following error:

*** ERROR: this process has called an NSArray-taking method, such as initWithArray:, and passed in an NSSet object.  This is being worked-around for now, but will soon cause you grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reduce your code:** Set NSFetchRequests only when you need to retrieve objects. Thus, you don't need the following lines every time you create new objects:

```
//Forms
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Forms")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

//Files
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Files")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
```

**Be consistent:** You have set NSManagedObject subclasses. So use them and don't use Key Value Coding. Replace:

```
newFormObject.setValue(uuid, forKey: "uuid")
```

with:

```
newFormObject.uuid = uuid
```

**Question:**

> How do i connect this 2 Objects?

A single line of code should be enough at the end of your loop:

```
newFileObject.forms = newFormObject // where forms is the name of your relationship
```

**Question:**

> how do i read all File Objects from a certain Form

When you need to retrieve `Files objects` of a certain `Form`, you can perform a NSFetchRequest (that allows you to set predicates, sorts and much more) or you can simply get a NSSet of all your related objects like this:

```
    //Get all Files objects (of a to-many relationship) related to a single Form object
    let filesSet = myForm.files as NSSet //where myForm is a Form managedObject
    let filesArray = filesSet.allObjects as Array

    for obj in filesArray as [Files] {
        println(obj.url)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: If i use: newFormObject.files = newFileObject the compiler told me: Files is not convertible to NSSet

Comment: So changed my NSSet to [Files] - but now: "Files is not identical to Anyobject"

Comment: newFileObject.forms = newFormObject;

Comment: Don't change your NSManagedObject subclasses. They look fine at the beginning of your post. Removing NSSet inside it will break your Core Data.

Comment: Try to delete your app and rebuild it. Every time you change your NSManagedObject subclasses, your app has to conform to your new Core Data Model.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Now i use: newFileObject.forms = newFormObject to set the relation in my loop for every file and no error at the moment. I will accept your answer - that brought me into the right direction!

Comment: Yes, you'r right: I set the declaration in the wrong way. I will edit my post.

Comment: But i changed still the NSSet into [Files] - everything seems to work fine now. Could this be a Problem?

Comment: Try to put back NSSet and see if it works (I'm pretty sure it will). Core Data returns an NSSet of objects linked with to-many relationship.

Comment: See my edit about NSSet that will answer your last post question.